Cannot set property of undefined, on all method
I'm currently a beginner to intermediate with JavaScript, and I'm trying to get used to intermediate JavaScript for development with template literals. I worked on a class to handle the heavy lifting of defining the template, but after many try, I'm still stuck on the same error.

Cannot set property of undefined

on all my method, and frankly have no idea why it act this way.

the error pop up to template.prototyp.ApplyCss but as soon as i remove it it goes to the next method and then the next...
and Object.freeze is innocent i removed it many time but nothing
arrow function don't do the job either

default async function TemplateElement(
    container,
    innerhtml,
    css = { fetchUrl: null, customCss: null },
    json = { fetchUrl: null, data: null },
    event = [{ type: null, selector: null, action: null }]
) {

    if (!container || typeof container !== "string") {
        throw new Error("Le conteneur doit être un nom de balise HTML valide ou un élément.");
    }
    if (typeof innerhtml !== "string") {
        throw new Error("innerhtml doit être une chaîne de caractères valide.");
    }

    this.template = {
        innerhtml: innerhtml || "",
        Json: json,
        container: container || "div",
        Css: css,
        event: event,
    };

    await this.applyCss();
    return this.contentHandler();
}

TemplateElement.prototype.applyCss = Object.freeze(async function () {
    function newStyle(data, id = null) {
        if (id && document.getElementById(id)) return;
        
        const style = document.createElement("style");
        if (id) style.id = id;
        style.innerText = data;
        style.type = "text/css";
        document.head.appendChild(style);
    }

    if (this.template.Css) {
        if (this.template.Css.fetchUrl) {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(this.template.Css.fetchUrl);
                const data = await response.text();
                newStyle(data, 'fetched-style'); // Assigner un ID pour le CSS récupéré
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Échec de la récupération du CSS :", error);
            }
        }
        if (this.template.Css.customCss) {
            newStyle(this.template.Css.customCss, 'custom-style'); // Assigner un ID pour le CSS personnalisé
        }
    }
});

TemplateElement.prototype.content = Object.freeze(function (data = {}) {
    const template = document.createElement(this.template.container);
    template.innerHTML = this.template.innerhtml;

    if (this.template.event) {
        this.eventHandler(template);
    }

    return template; // Élément HTML
});

TemplateElement.prototype.contentHandler = Object.freeze(async function () {
    let data = this.template.Json.data || {};

    if (this.template.Json.fetchUrl) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(this.template.Json.fetchUrl);
            const fetchedData = await response.json();
            data = { ...data, ...fetchedData }; // Fusionner les données récupérées avec les données existantes
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Erreur :", error);
        }
    }
    
    return this.content(data);
});

TemplateElement.prototype.eventHandler = Object.freeze(function (target) {
    const listenTo = [...new Set(this.template.event.map(event => event.type))];

    listenTo.forEach(eventType => {
        target.addEventListener(eventType, (e) => {
            this.locateChild(e.target, e.type); // Localiser l'élément d'événement et le type d'événement
        });
    });
});

TemplateElement.prototype.locateChild = Object.freeze(function (interactedWith, eventType) {
    this.template.event.forEach(({ type, selector, action }) => {
        if (type === eventType && interactedWith.matches(selector)) {
            action(); 
        }
    });
});


We can't help you because you've only posted partial error details - you need to also tell us which line the error happens on.

This question is similar to: Nodejs async function prototype chain error. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. (Async functions don't have prototype).

Do you instantiate the TemplateElement class with new?  const templateElement = new TemplateElement('div', '<p>Hello World</p>'); If you click [edit] and then the button marked [<>] you can make a [mcve]

Consider using arrow functions so the this will be inherited from the context of TemplateElement

@ mplungjan, it was that  i defined the class as Async function, and that sent back a promise not the object is was calling for. thanks
